# Ms Access VBa where condition with (And) Error

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, where-clause

i have a problem or lets say an error i get 
i'm having that "Run Time-error '13' type mismatch" error when running this code

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "hamw_m3amala_naw_w_mawad", acViewReport, , "Jori_Mawad = '" & Combo14 & "' " And "ID =" & Combo4
```

note that Jori_Mawad is String and ID is Number

and that this two condition without the (And) do not have any problem and works fine :

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "hamw_m3amala_naw_w_mawad", acViewReport, , "Jori_Mawad = '" & Combo14 & "'"

DoCmd.OpenReport "hamw_m3amala_naw_w_mawad", acViewReport, , "ID = " & Combo4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
And
```

should be within the string that you are using as a where clause, but you are instead And-ing the first part of your clause with the second.

try

```
"Jori_Mawad = '" & Combo14 & "' And ID =" & Combo4
```

Comment: thanks alot man , i don't know much about VBa and i really needed this , i tried it and it works fine now . again Thanks a ton man